# How i access to the second ul tag on css to change style with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

i have this html code:

```
        <div class="login">
            <ul class="preLogin" > 
                <div>
                    <li>
                        <input type="text" class="Nombre" id="name" placeholder="Usuario.."></li>  
                </div>
                <div>
                    <li>
                        <input type="password" class="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Contraseña.."></li>
                    </div>
                <div class="botonLogin" id="BotonLogin"><p>Entrar</p></div>
            </ul>
            <ul >
                <div>
                    <img src="./img/admin.png" alt="adminIcon" class="adminIcon" id="adminIcon">
                    <p class="textoPostLogin">¡Hola administrador!</p>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

this is the CSS

```
.preLogin{
  display: none;
}



.postLogin{
  display: none;
```

this is the file .js

```
jQuery('document').ready(function ($) {   
    var btnLogin = $('.botonLogin'),
    menu = $('.login ul');
    btnLogin.click(function(){
        
        var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
        var pass=document.getElementById("pass").value;
        if (name == "admin" && pass=="admin"){
            window.alert("Bienvenido a nuestro sitio web");
            menu.addClass('preLogin');
            menu.removeClass('postLogin');
        }
    });
});
```

what i want is do the same what the before js does but this time with the second ul:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maGSm.png)
i dont know how to access to that ul to put the css style postlogin to hidde o show the second ul.

thank you!!

i want to know how to acces the second UL to change the css style

Comment: The markup is invalid. `<div>` is not a valid child of an `<ul>`

Comment: you should first fix the invalid markup. Then you can use CSS selectors such as `nth-child` in jQuery or in JS `querySelector`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in javascript

```js
var ul2 = document.querySelectorAll("ul")[1];
ul2.style.background = "#000";
```

and in jquery you can use eq:

```js
$("ul").eq(1).css("background","#000");
```

Comment: easier to use `document.querySelector('ul:nth-of-type(2)')` instead of using `querySelectorAll` which will search the entire document, create a Node List and then need to select from that larger Node List instead of only selecting a single specific element

Comment: @ijavad you forget to add `jquery` CDN Url